# iPad - Problem with CLLocationManager & CLLocation property "course"

Tags: ipad, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I'm using CLLocationManager & CLLocation to get latitude and longitude of the location where iPad is.
Its working fine.
But when i'm trying to get the property "course" its always returning "-1"
What should I do to get the "course" property so that I can identify which direction is my iPad pointing to?

Comment: Although I have the same issue as you with the course property always returning -1 on iOS 4.2.1 on an iPhone 4, if you want the direction your iPad is "pointing to", what you really want is the `heading` field, which you enable by calling 'startUpdatingHeading' on suitable hardware.
'Course' is the direction the device is going, not pointing.

Answer (score 1):

Get up and start running, the gps needs to get several different values to determine a course/speed. I had to run with my iphone to get a value other than -1

Answer (score 0):

What are you testing this on?  Actual Hardware?  I think this is expected when using the simulator.  From the docs, a negative value indicates an "invalid" measurement, but that's all it says.

Comment: Even I tried using "LocateMe" example from Apple. That's also giving me -1 always